# "custom" xlDescending ordering

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of Dates, but some are "tbd". If I order them like so:

```
Range("A6:I100").CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=Range("A6"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess
```

it orders "tbd" before the actual dates. is it possible to reverse this? I want to have all dates - in descending order - first, and then all "tbd"s

thx

Comment: Assuming there isn't a better way of doing this, how about running a search/replace on the range first, replacing all `TBD` with a date such as `1901-12-31`, then sort, then reverse the replace?

Comment: Can you use a helper column ? E.g. column next to the values with `=ISNUMBER(A6)` (returns `TRUE` for a date) which you can include in the sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sorting you may try this:

```
Dim SortArr1 As Variant
SortArr1 = Array("tbd")
Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=SortArr1

Range("A6:I100").Sort key1:=Range("A6"), order1:=xlDescending, _
    Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=Application.CustomListCount + 1
Application.DeleteCustomList Application.CustomListCount
```